# iexpress assistance for my program

Tags: python, installation, iexpress

ok so i've used iexpress a few times without a problem. i created a nice little program for my buddies and i and i'm now in the process of creating a installation package for it. i like iexpress cause it makes it easy and has the license agreement window n whatnot.

ok so program is made. using windows & iexpress i attempt to make the installer, problem is there is one folder that contains an item i need and it needs to be in that folder directory when the installed program needs to run. Problem: i can select files but not folders for the list of items to be in the installer.

Question: how do i include the folder in the install package so there doesnt need to be a few more additional steps for the installation.

i have thought about zipping it, but there isnt a way (that i know of) to add a extract command after the initial install extract.

i figure installers are to programs what instruction booklets are to Ikea furniture so i figured this would be the best place for help. tyvm

Comment: sorry about the bold type. didn't know ampersand did that.

Comment: Why did you type a `#`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: i'm sorry im new, figured it'd be a way to add a side comment. like in python.

Answer (score 1):

iexpress doesn't let you include folders, but you can include a batch file, which may create folders and copy files to the respective folder. To run a batch file, specify *cmd /c IncludedBatchFile.bat* under *Install Program* in the iexpress wizard.